# Unable to run php script from my hosting cpanel

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, file-upload

I have domain and hosting. I want to run a php script of that domain. I uploaded that php files and follow their uploading instruction document. After uploading any php script normally i need to visit that domain link to begin script installing process. 
After extracting I visit my domain link. But It is not showing anything just showing "couldn't connect" .

I tried to upload it my other hosting provider with subdomain. I uploaded that php script files on my hosting subfolder. Then I tried to visit to that path/link. But still showing same problem. 
In this hosting I am running wordpress. It's working fine. But when i am trying to upload any php script it's not working.
Then, I tried again by uploading another php script. Still same problem but this time showing "Internal Server Error" message.
Thus, for testing purpose i tried to install it my xamp localhost. Then it showed installing process with lot of error(I think this errors showing because i am trying to work with localhost)

Now my question,
I want to run a php script in my hosting server. So before/after uploading files do i need to do any setting for that?
Is their any restriction/rules for running php files?
I am uploading 20MB files through cpanel. After extracting it's size increasing. So is it file uploading size issue?(I have enough disk space).

I am trying to run php script from 2 days and still not working.(Advertising php script one of them)

Comment: Sorry, we cannot say anything about restrictions your hosting provider might have implemented. You will have to ask them, not us. In general a php script does not have to be extracted or installed or anything. It is just a simple text file that has to be placed at a location where an http server is willing to interpret it. BTW: your error "couldn't connect" hints more towards either a networking issue or a probem with your http server, since it means that the protocol fails to connect even before a php script might come into play.

Comment: That means you are telling this may be hosting issues. But is it possible to show same problem on the different hosting? How can i solve the http server problem or protocol issues. Or those can solve only hosting provider?

Comment: I cannot tell you, since you do not show your code and setup. You stay vague, which is why I can only reply vague.

Comment: http://www.shortify.website check the link. This is showing after uploading files.

Comment: Sorry, no, I will certainly _not_ click on any link to some arbitrary site I do not know. Please post your (shortened/reduced) code and setup in the question. There is an `edit` button below it. Links to off-site pages are not well received here.

Comment: No. I am not asking to coding help. I am giving link to showing what kind of error are showing. After seeing, if you can give me some idea what's going wrong or what is the main issue.

Comment: Then post that error inside your question. Not a link, but the error message you receive.

Comment: Where are you upload the file? In your cPanel upload the file in public_html folder.

Comment: @Chayan yes I did that. I know about cpanel. I have few website. The main issue is that php script not working.